# Xdebug on Docker container inside Vagrant

Tags: docker, debugging, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I have configured Xdebug  inside PHP container which is run by docker-compose inside Vagrant.

What's the best way to get Xdebug working in PhpStorm, so how to expose docker container debugger info (port 9000) to establish connection with PhpStorm on enabled PHP Debug Connections listener. Since there are 2 communication layers (PC->Vagrant->Docker) PhpStorm probably can't access Docker.

I've tried with ngrok, it managed to "expose" docker container so PhpStorm can listen to port where Xdebug is, but somehow my whole page is broken when debugger is on, in this case and it is not working properly.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in PhpStorm: we're using temporary helper files & corresponding mappings to access Docker services & in case of Vagrant those mappings can't be applied correctly, because Vagrant setup uses another set of mappings.

Comment: I started getting some logs when using ngrok, but mine page renders broken, I assume it is because of mappings, it keeps asking for some files which are not existing on local machine, but are generated in Docker container (Symfony cache and vendor folders)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. IDE uses one set of helper files with Docker, and another with Vagrant. IDE can't use them both when one operates inside the other.